# Why do Clifford algebras determine $KO$ (and $K$-)-theory?

Tags: clifford-algebras, at.algebraic-topology

In the paper "Clifford modules" by Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro, they construct a family of Clifford algebras $C_k$ over the real numbers, so that $C_k$ is the algebra associated to a negative definite form on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $M_k$ be the Grothendieck group of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded $C_k$-modules. The authors define a map

$$ M_k \to \widetilde{KO}(S^k)$$
and similarly in complex $K$-theory.
The map is as follows: given a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded Clifford module $(N_0, N_1)$, one considers the constant vector bundles $\pi^*N_0, \pi^*N_1$ on the unit ball $B_k$ and the map $\pi^* N_1 \to \pi^*N_0$ which is given by Clifford multiplication by the vector in $B_k$. This is an isomorphism on $S^{k-1}$, so the "difference bundle" construction yields an element of $KO(B_k, S^{k-1} ) = \widetilde{KO}(S^k)$.

This map factors through the image of $M_{k+1}$ in $M_k$, and one thus gets a map of graded rings
$$\bigoplus M_k/M_{k+1} \to \bigoplus \widetilde{KO}^{-k}(\ast),$$
which they prove is an isomorphism, by using Bott periodicity and a bit of computation: one has to work out what the (purely algebraic) Grothendieck groups are, and then figure out which elements in $KO$-theory they correspond to. They remark that it would be nice to have a direct proof that the last map is an isomorphism; in particular, then one would be able to work out the $KO^\bullet(\ast)$ ring purely algebraically. Can this be done?

Comment: Nice question.  Can I object mildly to a point of terminology?  It seems that the modules in question are not "graded", which I think usually conotes something like "$\mathbb Z$-graded", but more like "super" or "$\mathbb Z/2$-graded", since you just want two of them.  More broadly, you probably know that Clifford algebras are most naturally part of superalgebra.  A Clifford algebra has a $\mathbb Z/2$-grading, which usually does not lift to a $\mathbb Z$-grading, given by putting the generators in odd degree.  (From this point of view, a Clifford algebra is exactly the Weyl algebra of a ...

Comment: ... purely odd presymplectic vector space, and this "explains" why the classical limit = associated graded is the symmetric algebra of said purely odd vector space.)  Anyway, then the representations of such an algebra _ought_ to be super, and I think this is what you really mean.  That said, I'm now confused by why you don't also use the Clifford multiplication $N_1 \to N_0$; it seems that the natural module structure has both, with composition = $\pm r^2$ times identity at radius $r$.

Comment: If you'll let me, I'm now going to ramble a little on something tangentially related, more to the title than the question. There's something I wish I understood further, which is the following. Given any reasonable symmetric monoidal category $C$, like the category of supervector spaces, you can form a ring whose elements are associative algebras in $C$ modulo Morita equivalence, $\times = \otimes$, and $+ = \oplus$.  (Really I mean elements are reasonable $C$-module categories, with $\otimes$ and $\oplus$ of categories.) Then you can take the group of units in this ring. This is the ...

Comment: @Theo: I just changed the notation from "graded" to "$\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded." The choice of $N_0 \to N_1$ versus $N_1 \to N_0$ only changes the map  by a sign (the difference bundle is only really dependent on the vector bundles involved, not the maps); however, the paper actually uses $N_1\to N_0$ so I've just fixed that. I think it is sort of interesting, actually, that the grading enters in such an essential way to constructing the map. 

Comment: ... _Brauer group_ of $C$. (One categorical dimension down, the same construction builds the Picard group of a commutative ring $C$.) Anyway, the statement is that for $C = $supervect, the representatives of Brauer are certain Clifford algebras, and over $\mathbb R$ this "super" Brauer group is a $\mathbb Z/8$ and is the same $\mathbb Z/8$ that shows up in Bott periodicity and KO-theory.  But I've never really understood (in a deep way) why all of these are the same.  Anyway, you probably know all this, and I sadly have nothing useful to say to your actual question.

Comment: By the way, I wasn't aware of the "super" Brauer group and that it gave a $\mathbb{Z}/8$ (and presumably over $\mathbb{C}$ a $\mathbb{Z}/2$?). Thanks for bringing this to my attention. 

Comment: I deleted my answer. Woods paper states the periodicity result in terms of homogeneous spaces and does not discuss why his result does give the ABS isomorphism, which is a pity, because is not as trivial as I thought.

Comment: @Theo; I don't know how much it helps, but there are Baez's copy of Trimble's notes, http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/trimble/superdivision.html which goes a little further, that the super-Brauer classes are all represented by superdivision algebras. Hmmm... since I've said "goes further", I probably ought to check that superdivision algebras are also clifford algebras. Does it seem plausible, at least?

Comment: @Whomever, when last I was playing with these Clifford gadgets, a remarkably helpful tool was, for an embedding $C_k \to C_l$, to consider the commutant of $C_k$ in $C_l$; and it was a further helpful fact that the group of units in each of these commutants deformation-retracts to one of the compact classical groups $O, Sp, U$ or their squares, in the usual suspicious pattern. I'm afraid I can't say, though, how far this helps in producing an "algebraic" construction of $K?$; I was content to rely on Bott's Morse functions.

Comment: @Johannes: I agree that the paper doesn't quite answer Akhil's question.  But why delete the answer?  It included some useful references for interlocutors like me.

Comment: @some guy: Thanks for the link.  I think I had seen it, but not for some time.  The version of the story that I know is in the lecture notes from Richard Borcherds' contribution to the Berkeley Lie Groups course from 2006.  I've included it in my (slowly growing) collection on notes on Lie and Quantum groups at http://math.berkeley.edu/~theojf/LieQuantumGroups.pdf (section 7.3.1).  Richard just cites Todd's notes.

Comment: This was done here: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/askew.pdf . The idea was that similar to how the space of Fredholm operators classifies K-theory, the space $F^k$ of "Fredholm operator automorphisms" of a Hilbert space representation represents $KO^{-k}$, and the kernel map defines an isomorphism between $\pi_0(F^k) \to M_k/M_{k+1}$.